# Сonvert the pointcloud data to laserscan

Tags: ros, roslaunch, nodes, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, ROS Community!
I have a problem in understanding of the nodes from launch file.
kinect_to_laser.launch:

```
<launch>
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"></include>
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="openni_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"></node>
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager">
<param name="max_rate" value="2"></param>
<remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"></remap>
<remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"></remap></node>
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager">
<param name="output_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_frame"></param>
<remap from="cloud" to="cloud_throttled"></remap>
</node>
```

When I run the launch file, I get the errors that openni_manager, pointcloud_throttle and kinect_laser nodes are not exist.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByuHYHQ3iNnKZ0ltVVJIZm4xb1U

I figure out that they are not exist, but what can I use ?

Pls, explain me what I can do and I will be glad to get any other full answer about sensor data manipulation

Distribution: Indigo
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Sensor: Kinect XBOX 360
openni.launch runs without errors

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213713/%D1%81onvert-the-pointcloud-data-to-laserscan/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2015-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-14**:
Did you install pointcloud_to_laserscan?

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2015-07-14**:
Yes, I have the package that is located /opt/ros/indigo/share/pointcloud_to_laserscan.

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2015-07-15**:
does it not matter that my package with launch file is not in catkin workplace?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-15**:
According to the list in the error message I suspect the nodelet was renamed. There is only one left in the list named pointcloud_to_laserscan_nodelet. Maybe try this one instead and remove the throttle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was searching the answer to my question and there is tfoote's answer that I paid attention : http://answers.ros.org/question/9450/how-to-setup-pointcloud_to_laserscan/

"Sorry the docs were out of date. It has moved from the ni stack to the turtlebot stack. It's a unreviewed/released glue package used in the turtlebot ...."

pointcloud_to_laserscan package belongs to Turtlebot's stack. In the Turtlebot page http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup , I found packages as cloud_throttle and others in electric and fuerte distributions that are not listed in indigo and hydro. I would like to say that the packages are not included in last ROS distributions. OR maybe, the packages were renamed ...
Am I right?

As you advised, I removed nodes and my launch file looks like :

```
<launch>
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"></include>
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager">
<param name="output_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_frame"></param>
<remap from="cloud" to="cloud_throttled"></remap>
</node>
</launch>
```

And, the result :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByuHYHQ3iNnKT1d1OVJuZktwMllVQk1FVmc3QjlKc1U2MVZ3

So, it is clear that the launch file runs only openni.launch, that it was not my initial task.

I was trying to follow your advice, but I dont understand what i should write in name=" " and type=" ". I know that I need to run a container for all nodelets, a nodelet for handling frequency of cloud points and a nodelet for cutting horizontal segments. But, I dont know the syntax and what the package I can use.

Here http://answers.ros.org/question/188444/convert-point-cloud-data-into-laserscan-in-ros-indigo/ , the question is the same as mine, but author understood the answers without any explanation, not like me.
Dont you know how to use depthimage_to_laserscan ?

The problem is solved!

```
<launch>
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>
<remap from="image" to="/camera/depth/image_raw"/>
<node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan">
</node>
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"/>
</launch>
```

My fault was in misunderstanding. I thought that depthimage_to_laserscan replaced openni_launch and I cannot use them together...
Thank you, dornhege, for your answers

---

Originally posted by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) with karma: 200 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-15**:
The nodelet name after load seems to have been renamed. Replace it by the matching one in the long list in your error.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-16**:
In that case I'd just start the node and use that.